# Как получить одномерный список после обращения к БД (psycopg2)

Tags: psycopg2

Всем привет!

Подскажите как приянто получать `flat list/set` если нужно выбрать только 1 колонку из БД?
По дефолту `DB-API` всегда требует возвращать `nested list`, пример: `ids = [(1,). (2,), (3,),]`.

`sqlite3` вроде как умеет делать это автоматом с помощью `row_factory`, может быть и `psycopg2` такое умеет? В доках не нашел упоминания.

Я пока распаковываю через `list comprehension`, но не понятно в какой момент лучше/принято распаковывать, сразу после использования `fetchall` или после вызова `crud` функции, которая под капотом вызывает `fetchall`?

```
# Crud function, var 1
def read_user_photos(id: int, cursor) -> set:  # Var 1
    cursor.execute('SELECT photo FROM photos WHERE id = %s', (id,))
    return [photos_lst[0] for photos_lst in cursor.fetchall()]

# Some class method that uses crud, var 2
photos = [photo_lst[0] for photo_lst in read_user_photos(id, cursor)]  # Var 2
do anything_with_photos(photos=photos)
```

Comment: fetchone()[0] + yield не годится?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич А как поможет `yield` не понимаю?

Comment: не знаю контекста использования Вашего photos, потому могу только догадываться - поможет ли. Но в общем случае где то у вас там есть же итератор, который жаждет на входе данных из iterable структуры, и экспепшена StopIteration...  Вот тут yield ему и "ответчик".